# How to rename the default property name I can call an NPM package API with?

Tags: vue.js, npm

For example, I want to use two similar libraries: [@meforma/vue-toaster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@meforma/vue-toaster) and [vue-toastification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toastification).
Both of them set a `.$toast` property to the context to call their API.
Can I rename these properties, for example to `$toast1` and `$toast2`? If not how can I use both of them if I want to register them globally?

Vue version - 3

Comment: It's unknown which version you using. You can rename global properties in your own plugin that is executed in the middle.

Comment: @EstusFlask Vue 3, added to the description